# repo.path returns nothing even after creating an initializing a rugged repo

Tags: git, libgit2, rugged

I created a git repository using the below code in rugged..

```
require 'rugged'
$repopath='D:\Test12'
Rugged::Repository.init_at($repopath, true)
repo = Rugged::Repository.new($repopath)
puts repo.path
```

however, I didn't get any output when I execute the above code as ruby myfile.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backslash didn't help.. downloaded 0.17.0.b7 and it worked.. was working on 0.16 earlier..

Answer (score 0):

The backslash should be doubled: `$repopath='D:\\Test12'`

Comment: backslash didn't help.. downloaded 0.17.0.b7 and it worked.. was working on 0.16 earlier..